How to Handle Large REST API Responses in Oracle APEX Exceeding Page Item Character Limits
I’m making a REST API POST request from an Oracle APEX page, passing parameters stored in page items. The API response contains around 60,000 characters, and I’ve set an OUT parameter to store the response in a page item (e.g., P2_RESPONSE). However, it seems the page item can only handle around 30,000 characters, and as a result, half of my JSON response is being truncated.
Is there a better way to handle large API responses in Oracle APEX, or is there a way to increase the character limit of a page item to accommodate the full response?

Starting with APEX 22.2, you can navigate to your page item attributes in Page Designer, look up the Session State section and change the session state data type to CLOB. That is available for Hidden, Textarea and Rich text items. Once that is in place, you should be able to receive large responses also ... does that work?

Changed the session state. it worked!
